# Command line input to a C program (using 'print' command of Perl)

Tags: c, perl, debugging, command-line, gdb

I am having difficulty in understanding the way `print` command of Perl interprets the hexadecimal values. I am using a very simple program of just 8 lines to demonstrate my question. Following code with `gdb` will explain my question in detail:

```
anil@anil-Inspiron-N5010:~/Desktop$ gcc -g code.c
anil@anil-Inspiron-N5010:~/Desktop$ gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   
3   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
4   {
5       int i;
6       for (i =0; i<argc; ++i)
7           printf ("%p\n", argv[i]);
8       return 0;
9   }
(gdb) break 8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40057a: file code.c, line 8.
(gdb) run $(perl -e 'print "\xdd\xcc\xbb\xaa"') $(perl -e 'print "\xcc\xdd\xee\xff"')
Starting program: /home/anil/Desktop/a.out $(perl -e 'print "\xdd\xcc\xbb\xaa"') $(perl -e 'print "\xcc\xdd\xee\xff"')
0x7fffffffe35d
0x7fffffffe376
0x7fffffffe37b

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffdfe8) at code.c:8
8       return 0;
(gdb) x/2x argv[1]
0x7fffffffe376: 0xaabbccdd  0xeeddcc00
```

In above shown lines I have used `gdb` to debug the program. As command line arguments, I have passed two (hexadecimal) arguments (excluding the name of the program itself): `\xdd\xcc\xbb\xaa` and `\xcc\xdd\xee\xff`. Owing to the little-endian architecture, those arguments should be interpreted as `0xaabbccdd` and `0xffeeddcc` but as you can see the last line of above shown debugging shows `0xaabbccdd` and `0xeeddcc00`. Why is this so? What am I missing ?? This has happened with some other arguments too. I am requesting you to help me with this.

PS: 2^32 = 4294967296 and `0xffeeddcc` = 4293844428 (2^32 > `0xffeeddcc`). I don't know if still there is any connection.

Comment: Endianness is how multi-byte scalar values such as `int` are stored. The arguments to your programs are strings. (It would be a bit silly if Little-Endian machines printed "lleHow o!dlr", wouldn't it?)

Comment: the input of the form \x##\x##\x##\x## shows that they contain hexadecimal values, hence they need to be interpreted bit differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command-line arguments are NUL-terminated strings.

Arguments `argv[1]` is a pointer to the first character of a NUL-terminated string.

```
7FFFFFFFE376  DD CC BB AA 00
```

`argv[2]` is a pointer to the first character of a NUL-terminated string.

```
7FFFFFFFE37B  CC DD EE FF 00
```

If you pay attention, you'll notice they happen to be located immediately one after the other in memory.

```
7FFFFFFFE376  DD CC BB AA 00 CC DD EE FF 00
```

You asked to print two (32-bit) integers starting at `argv[1]`

```
7FFFFFFFE376  DD CC BB AA 00 CC DD EE FF 00
              ----------- -----------
               0xAABBCCDD 0xEEDDCC00
```

For `x/2x` to be correct, you would have needed to use

```
perl -e'print "\xdd\xcc\xbb\xaa\xcc\xdd\xee\xff"'
   -or-
perl -e'print pack "i*", 0xaabbccdd, 0xffeeddcc'
```

For the arguments you passed, you need to use

```
(gdb) x argv[1]
0x3e080048cbd:  0xaabbccdd
(gdb) x argv[2]
0x3e080048cc2:  0xffeeddcc
```

Comment: yes, I know realize why other arguments too were giving similar results. thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: In case the run command is following:
`run $(perl -e 'print "\xaa\xbb\x00\xcc"') $(perl -e 'print "\xaa\xbb\xcc\x00"') $(perl -e 'print "\xaa\x00\xdd\xcc"')`
the expected result on x/15xb argv[1] is: `0xaa 0xbb 0x00 0xcc 0x00 0xaa  0xbb 0xcc 0x00 0x00 0xaa 0x00 0xdd 0xcc 0x00` in which the 5th, 10th and 15th `0x00` should belong to null terminator but the actual output is: `0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0x00 0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0x00 0xaa 0xdd  0xcc 0x00 0x58 0x44 0x47` in which I think `0x00` of the input has been ignored, only `0x00` corresponding to null-terminator has been considered. Any explanation??

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing yourself by printing strings as numbers. In a little-endian architecture, in a four-byte value such as 0xDDCCBBAA, the bytes are numbered *left-to-right* from the starting address.

So let's take a look at the output of your debugger command:

```
(gdb) x/2x argv[1]
0x7fffffffe376: 0xaabbccdd  0xeeddcc00
```

Looking at that byte by byte, it would be:

```
0x7fffffffe376: dd
0x7fffffffe377: cc
0x7fffffffe378: bb
0x7fffffffe379: aa

0x7fffffffe37a: 00  # This NUL terminates argv[1]
0x7fffffffe37b: cc  # This address corresponds to argv[2]
0x7fffffffe37c: dd
0x7fffffffe37d: ee
```

Which is not unexpected, no?

You might want to use something like this to display arguments in hex:

```
x/8bx argv[1]
```

(which will show **8** **b**ytes in he**x**adecimal)

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistake, was mistakenly ignoring the NUL-terminator.

Comment: In case the run command is following:
`run $(perl -e 'print "\xaa\xbb\x00\xcc"') $(perl -e 'print "\xaa\xbb\xcc\x00"') $(perl -e 'print "\xaa\x00\xdd\xcc"')`
the expected result on `x/15xb argv[1]` is: `0xaa 0xbb 0x00 0xcc 0x00 0xaa  0xbb 0xcc 0x00 0x00 0xaa 0x00 0xdd 0xcc 0x00` in which the 5th, 10th and 15th `0x00` should belong to null terminator but the actual output is: `0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0x00 0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0x00 0xaa 0xdd  0xcc 0x00 0x58 0x44 0x47` in which it seems that `0x00` of the input has been ignored, only `0x00` corresponding to null-terminator has been considered. Any explanation??

Comment: @aniliitb10: bash strings cannot contain NULs. Or, more accurately, bash strings are always terminated with a NUL. So the result of `$(printf '\xaa\xbb\x00\xcc')` (which is the same as your perl print statement) is effectively a NUL-terminated string of two characters, `\xaa\xbb`.

Comment: no, output shows that it is effectively a string of three characters, `\xaa\xbb\xcc` terminated with a NUL character. Can it just skip `\x00` and proceed again to print `\xcc` as it did in `$(perl -e 'print "\xaa\xbb\x00\xcc" ')` ??

Comment: @aniliitb10: Interesting. You're right, bash removes the NULs from the string, rather than terminating the string when it hits one. I stand corrected. But either way, bash strings cannot contain NUL characters.